# Example of time-dependent constant of motion in classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets, integrals-of-motion

In classical mechanics text, when learning about Poisson brackets, one gets
$\frac{df}{dt} = \{f,H\} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system and for $\frac{df}{dt}=0$, $f$ is a constant of motion. It is taught that if there is no explicit time-dependence in $f$, then $\{f,H\}=0$.

However, I am just wondering if there is any obvious example for which $f$ has an explicit time-dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Example: a free particle in 1D:* $$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}.$$
Two constants of motion are $$p\quad\text{ and }\quad x-\frac{p}{m}t.$$
The latter depends explicitly on $t$.

Comment: While the math checks out, in what sense is the quantity $x-\frac{p}{m} t$, essentially the displacement, a "constant"?

Comment: It is a [constant of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion), i.e. it doesn't change in time.

Comment: The second constant of motion arises from invariance in form of the Hamiltonian under classical boosts...